# Google Map API v3 multiple marker with labels/text

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I found a solution on placing label/text on the google map marker. Which is found in this link http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerwithlabel/1.1.8/docs/reference.html

My problem is the markers are placed in one place. But the label/text on each marker is placed on the correct points. Can anyone help me?

The code below is inside a $.each() jQuery function for looping.

```
geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address }, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        var contentString = "sample text";

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: contentString;
        });

        var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
            position: results[0].geometry.location,
            map: map,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            title: address,
            labelContent: lblAddress,
            labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(7, 30),
            labelClass: "map-labels", // the CSS class for the marker
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infowindow.open(map, this);
        });
}
```

[image]

The image above shows the markers of two different points is shown in one place. I'm sure about it because when I click the label "18107 Gold Mesa" a infowindow will open, but the infowindow will show on the "3611 Alonzo Fields". There are two markers on that point.

But when I don't used the 3rd party library. The markers are placed on the correct points. using the google map method on placing markers. `new google.maps.Marker`

Thanks,
Justin

Answer (score 0):

use infowindow.open(map, marker);

instead of

infowindow.open(map, this);

I guess this will show your popup near the label only and your may find some substantial reason for markers not showing up

Comment: It doesn't fix my problem.